# Is there a way to create a css3 border gradient to a specific pixel?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I know this is possible with background gradients but cannot figure out how to implement this for border gradients.

Here's what I have so far

```
-webkit-border-image  : -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#666), to(#000)) 1 100%; 
-webkit-border-image  : -webkit-linear-gradient(#666, #000) 1 100%; 
-moz-border-image     : -moz-linear-gradient(#666, #000) 1 100%; 
-o-border-image       : -o-linear-gradient(#666, #000) 1 100%; 
border-image          : linear-gradient(to bottom, #666, #000) 1 100%;
```

I would like the first 32px from the bottom up to be black, and then the rest going upwards grey (#666).

[image: Here is an example of what I would like my right border to look like]

Comment: Probably easier to “fake” the border by using an additional container element that gets a background and padding, or a positioned pseudo element …

Comment: @CBroe I would definitely go the `::after` route here.

Comment: I too would use an `::after` selector for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you do it like so :
using a `pseudo-element` like `:before` which you position at `bottom:0` and `left:-15px` , because `15px` is the width of the border. if you change the `border-width` you change `left:-15px`

the same for it's `width:15px`

i used `width:15px` and `background:#000` but you could simply use `border-left:15px solid #000`  instead of those two. the result is the same.

```css
.borderme {
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  border-left:15px solid #666;

}
.borderme:before {
  position:absolute;
  height:32px;
  width:15px;
  background:#000;
  bottom:0;
  left:-15px;

  content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="borderme">

</div>
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you for your efforts.